# Does Poser 8 work in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

I have just bought Poser8 but it crashes on Windows7 on my computer. This maybe linked to the absence of a Library? The display of Poser8 only shows a white screen.
Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, Poser 8 is reported to work in Windows 7:

"Officially supports **Windows 7** and Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6)" ([source](http://poser.smithmicro.com/update_files/Poser8SR3ReadMe.rtf))

But ensure you install the latest [Poser 8 updates](http://poser.smithmicro.com/poser8updates.html).